# Android: Roboelectic test throws error from Application.onCreate

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing, dagger-hilt

When trying to start one of my tests, Robolectric throws an error, saying that one of my variables in my custom `Application Class` is not initialized (`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property workerList has not been initialized`). This might be due to the fact, that my lateinit property `workerList` will be initialized with dagger-hilt later on.

### Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
    @Inject lateinit var workerList: WorkerList // this causes the problem
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        plantTimberTree()
        workerList.startDownloadDocumentWork() // this causes the problem
    }

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
        Configuration.Builder().setWorkerFactory(workerFactory).build()
}
```

When removing `workerList.startDownloadDocumentWork()`, all of my test cases work again. How can I solve the problem in a way without removing `workerList.startDownloadDocumentWork()`?

### Stacktrace

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property workerList has not been initialized

    at com.example.app.App.onCreate(App.kt:21)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:171)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:319)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:254)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You answered your own question. You need to do the injection before `onCreate` since `onCreate` references `workerList`.

Comment: @Benjamin Not in `dagger-hilt`, injection happens here IN `super.onCreate()` therefore, the variable is only accessible AFTER `super.onCreate()`. Please refer to [this](https://dagger.dev/hilt/quick-start)

Comment: Right. But you're talking about in the context of Robolectric. Are you sure that the injection is happening after you create your App when it's being tested?

Comment: I am not testing any `Activity` or `UI`, I am just doing simple unit-testing. I don't even need my `workerList` variable in my test, the variable is only needed for production. The injection IS NOT HAPPENING when it's being tested and it is not even possible that the injection can happen. Furthermore, I only need the injection, when there is no test being executed, something like "if(!testing) {  inject stuff }

Comment: It looks like Robolectric is somehow creating the application in a different way than the Android framework and therefore `workerList` isn't being injected with Hilt.

Comment: Yeah that might be the issue... Is there a way to "detect" in my Application class, whether a roboelectric / junit test is running?

Answer (score 0):

If these lines are not required for your test with Robolectric, you can create a custom application class and use it with Robolectric instead.

`class TestApp : Application()`

In your test add:
`@Config(application = TestApp::class)`